# Load Nodejs Module into A Web Worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, requirejs, web-worker

I'm intending to use web worker inside my Node.js application for some concurrent tasks. However since the `'webworker-threads'` module follows the implementation of HTML5 web worker, requiring Nodejs modules like `require("fs")` inside web worker does not work. `importScripts()` can load js files but I would like a functionality inside the web worker so that I can `require` npm-installed modules. Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

author of webworker-threads here. Thank you for using the module!

There is a default `native_fs_` object with the `readFileSync` you can use to read files.

Beyond that, I've mostly relied on onejs to compile all required modules in `package.json` into a single JS file for `importScripts` to use, just like one would do when deploying to a client-side web worker environment. (There are also many alternatives to onejs -- browserify, etc.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: __@audreyt__ can you import modules that depend on other modules this way, as long as they are mentioned in `package.json`?

Comment: Would it be possible to load node modules that use native resources, like `v4l2camera`?