# Webworker-threads: is it OK to use "require" inside worker?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, sails.js, web-worker

(Using Sails.js)

I am testing webworker-threads ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads ) for long running processes on Node and the following example looks good:

```
var Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
var fibo = new Worker(function() {
    function fibo (n) {
        return n > 1 ? fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2) : 1;
    }
    this.onmessage = function (event) {
        try{
            postMessage(fibo(event.data));                

        }catch (e){
            console.log(e);                
        }
    }
});
fibo.onmessage = function (event) {
    //my return callback
};
fibo.postMessage(40);
```

But as soon as I add any code to query Mongodb, it throws an exception:
(not using the Sails model in the query, just to make sure the code could run on its own -- db has no password)

```
var Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
var fibo = new Worker(function() {
    function fibo (n) {
        return n > 1 ? fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2) : 1;
    }
    // MY DB TEST -- THIS WORKS FINE OUTSIDE THE WORKER
    function callDb(event){
        var db = require('monk')('localhost/mydb');
        var users = db.get('users');
        users.find({ "firstName" : "John"}, function (err, docs){
            console.log(("serviceSuccess"));
            return fibo(event.data);
        });
    }
    this.onmessage = function (event) {
        try{

            postMessage(callDb(event.data));     // calling db function now           

        }catch (e){
            console.log(e);                
        }
    }
});
fibo.onmessage = function (event) {
    //my return callback
};
fibo.postMessage(40);
```

Since the DB code works perfectly fine outside the Worker, I think it has something to do with the `require`. I've tried something that also works outside the Worker, like

```
 var moment = require("moment");
 var deadline = moment().add(30, "s");
```

And the code also throws an exception. Unfortunately, console.log only shows this for all types of errors:

```
{Object}
{/Object}
```

So, the questions are: is there any restriction or guideline for using require inside a Worker? What could I be doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

it seems Threads will not allow external modules
https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo/issues/22

> TL:DR I think that if you need to require, you should use a node's
>   cluster or child process. If you want to offload some cpu busy work,
>   you should use tagg and the load function to grab any helpers you
>   need.

Upon reading this thread, I see that this question is similar to this one:
[Load Nodejs Module into A Web Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107521/load-nodejs-module-into-a-web-worker)

To which Audreyt, the webworker-threads author answered:

> author of webworker-threads here. Thank you for using the module!
>
> There is a default native_fs_ object with the readFileSync you can use
>   to read files.
>
> Beyond that, I've mostly relied on onejs to compile all required
>   modules in package.json into a single JS file for importScripts to
>   use, just like one would do when deploying to a client-side web worker
>   environment. (There are also many alternatives to onejs -- browserify,
>   etc.)
>
> Hope this helps!

So it seems `importScripts` is the way to go. But at this point, it might be too *hacky* for what I want to do, so probably `KUE` is a more mature solution.

Comment: If you write `console.log(err.message)` instead of just `console.log(err)` you will see `require is not defined` instead of `{Object}{/Object}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I guess that falls into the "Threads will not allow external modules" issue.

Comment: I don't see how this is hacky. Your thread doesn't share objects with the main userland thread. You just have to do manually what Node does automagically on the main thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a collaborator on the [node-webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) project.

### You can't `require` in `node-webworker-threads`

You are correct in your update: `node-webworker-threads` does not (currently) support `require`ing external modules.

It has limited support for some of the built-ins, including file system calls and a version of `console.log`. As you've found, the version of `console.log` implemented in `node-webworker-threads` is not identical to the built-in `console.log` in Node.js; it does not, for example, automatically make nice string representations of the components of an Object.

In some cases you **can** use external modules, as outlined by audreyt in her response. Clearly this is not ideal, and I view the incomplete `require` as the primary "dealbreaker" of `node-webworker-threads`. I'm hoping to work on it this summer.

### When to use `node-webworker-threads`

`node-webworker-threads` allows you to code against the WebWorker API and run the same code in the client (browser) and the server (Node.js). This is why you would use `node-webworker-threads` over [node-threads-a-gogo](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo).

`node-webworker-threads` is great if you want the most lightweight possible JavaScript-based workers, to do something CPU-bound. Examples: prime numbers, Fibonacci, a Monte Carlo simulation, offloading built-in but potentially-expensive operations like regular expression matching.

### When **not** to use `node-webworker-threads`

`node-webworker-threads` emphasizes portability over convenience. For a Node.js-only solution, this means that `node-webworker-threads` is not the way to go.

If you're willing to compromise on full-stack portability, there are two ways to go: speed and convenience.

For **speed**, try a [C++ add-on](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). Use [NaN](https://github.com/nodejs/nan). I recommend Scott Frees's [C++ and Node.js Integration](https://nodeaddons.com/book/) book to learn how to do this, it'll save you a lot of time. You'll pay for it in needing to brush up on your C++ skills, and if you want to work with MongoDB then this probably isn't a good idea.

For **convenience**, use a [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)-based worker pool like [fork-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fork-pool). In this case, each worker is a full-fledged Node.js instance. You can then `require` to your heart's content. You'll pay for it in a larger application footprint and in higher communication costs compared to `node-webworker-threads` or a C++ add-on.