# Webworker-threads in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I am a NodeJS newbie from C# world still trying to understand the complex JavaScript maze.
I am trying to implement the multi-threading from the example on https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads.

Can not understand why the below works:

```
var Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
var FibCalculator = require('./FibCalculator.js');

require('http').createServer(function (req,res) {
  console.log('request received.');
  var fibo = new Worker(function() {
    var calcFib = function (n) {
      return n > 1 ? calcFib(n - 1) + calcFib(n - 2) : 1;
    };
    this.onmessage = function (event) {
      postMessage(calcFib(event.data));
    };
  });
  fibo.onmessage = function (event) {
    var msg = 'fib(5) = ' + event.data;
    console.log(msg);
    res.end(msg);
  };
  fibo.postMessage(5);
}).listen(3000);
```

But the below just does not

```
var Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
var FibCalculator = require('./FibCalculator.js');

//the below function just does not get called
var calcFib = function (n) {
    console.log('***This will not print. Can someone explain why?***');
    return n > 1 ? calcFib(n - 1) + calcFib(n - 2) : 1;
};

require('http').createServer(function (req,res) {
  console.log('request received.');
  var fibo = new Worker(function() {    
    this.onmessage = function (event) {
      postMessage(calcFib(event.data));
    };
  });
  fibo.onmessage = function (event) {
    var msg = 'fib(5) = ' + event.data;
    console.log(msg);
    res.end(msg);
  };
  fibo.postMessage(5);
}).listen(3000);
```

Why is it that if I take out the scope of calcFib, it cannot get called. My idea was to implement a wrapper over webworker-threads that could be used to perform any CPU intrinsic operations on another thread. However, I am not even able to call an external function

**Below is reply to Benjamin Gruenbaum answer:**

How can I call console.log inside onmessage but not my function defined outside the scope in the same file?

```
this.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log('can call console.log even if it is external');
  //cannot call calcFib(event.data) if it is defined outside the scope.
  postMessage(calcFib(event.data));
};
```

Comment: Are you simply interested in workers? Node is highly performant without a need for multithreading.

Comment: NodeJS runs on a single thread and hence not recommended for a cpu intensive operation as it will block other callers. The reason I am interested in workers is for those one-off use cases where you need cpu intensive operations

Comment: Ah. I missed the calc fib. Sorry. Btw, i may be mistaken, but js before es6 did not support tail call recursion. You might not want to use node for that just yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workers work by *copying the code* over so all closure data is lost. You cannot access closure scope from within the worker so `calcFib` is undefined.

You need to define `calcFib` *inside* the worker code or send it via a message and `eval` it.

```
var Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
var FibCalculator = require('./FibCalculator.js');

require('http').createServer(function (req,res) {
  console.log('request received.');

  var fibo = new Worker(function() {    
    //the below function just does not get called
    var calcFib = function (n) {
      console.log('***This will not print. Can someone explain why?***');
      return n > 1 ? calcFib(n - 1) + calcFib(n - 2) : 1;
    };
    this.onmessage = function (event) {
      postMessage(calcFib(event.data));
    };
  });
  fibo.onmessage = function (event) {
    var msg = 'fib(5) = ' + event.data;
    console.log(msg);
    res.end(msg);
  };
  fibo.postMessage(5);
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Still dont understand: how can I call a system function like console.log(...) inside onmessage bt not my function defined in the same file:

    this.onmessage = function (event) {
      //Console.log works:
     console.log('this works');
     //but this does not calcFib(event.data) if calcFib is defined outside the scope
    };

Comment: Because the function is .toString'd and copied

Answer (score 2):

I am a collaborator on the [node-webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) project.

#### Why your code doesn't work

`node-webworker-threads` workers must be taught all of the functionality they are asked to perform. They exist in a separate **namespace**, so they can't see things present even in the same file unless you specifically tell them about it. You tell them about the necessary functions using `node-webworker-threads`'s `load` and `eval` APIs.

#### What `node-webworker-threads` workers can do

`node-webworker-threads` workers can perform native JavaScript functionality, like arrays and objects, interacting with JSON and regular expressions and so on. These workers also support *some* of the Node.js-specific built-ins, like console.log. This is why you can call `console.log` (a supported built-in) but not your function (outside of the worker's namespace). As noted [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42252324/2591870), in some cases the `node-webworker-threads` implementations of the built-in APIs are not a perfect match.