# Requiring file in webworker-threads nodejs multithreading

Tags: node.js, multithreading, ecmascript-6, web-worker, worker

I'm using https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads library for nodejs multithreading.

As stated in [Webworker-threads in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959252/webworker-threads-in-nodejs) I cannot just reference a function in the same file, I have to load the worker job with the library utilities.

I'm using ES6 and babel transpiler and run my project with npm.

So I have this:

```
// index.js
const startWorker = () => {

    console.log('creating worker:');

    const myWorker = new Worker (

        () => {
            console.log('in worker');

            self.importScripts('workerJob.js');

            self.postMessage('done');
        }

    );

    myWorker.onmessage = (event) => {console.log(event.data);};

};


//workerJob.js
console.log('worker job');
```

When I comment `self.importScripts` it works ok and print's out 'done' message, but when I try to import with `self.importScripts('workerJob.js')` the program hangs. I also tried `self.importScripts('./workerJob.js')`.

Program structure looks like this:

```
- root
  -  backend
     - src
         - index.js
         - workerJob.js
     - package.json
```

I also use nodemon to run this live.

How to import worker's job code?